# How to exclude methods from code profiling

Tags: dottrace, code-profiling

I am executing code profiling with dotTrace, and I would like to be able to exclude specific methods from the code profiling - namely the ones that call external services and whose performance I do not control.
Is there a way to do this? I am trying to filter my results using dotTrace subsystems, but I am not being able to "hide" these method calls from the profiling results.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To exclude some method from call tree, you can just press Del or Shift+Del on it.
See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Studying_Profiling_Results__Performance_Forecasting.html for Sampling/Tracing/Line-by-line and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Forecasting_Performance_Timeline.html for Timeline profiling mode.

If you are using Line-by-line profiling mode, you can profile only particular methods using filters: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Profiler_Options.html#filters